# Does the Rejang language have a Latin orthography in use?

Tags: writing-systems

There is a  Malayo-Polynesian language in Bengkulu, Indonesia with about 350,000 speakers called [Rejang, Redjang, or Rejangese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejang_language_(Sumatra)).

[It has its own native Brahmic abugida.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejang_alphabet)

But I'm wondering if it also has a Latin orthography which is used to a degree equal to or greater than the native script. It could also be possible that all writing is in the national language, Indonesian, leaving Rejang as mostly a spoken language in modern times.

Information in Wikipedia and the Internet generally is sparse. Some solid information on whether and to which degree Rejang is written in Latin script would be appreciated.

Comment: It appears to have been phonemicized, judging from [the Ethnologue report](http://www.ethnologue.com/language/rej). The abugida is described [here](http://scriptsource.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=script_detail&key=Rjng), and the online resources at OLAC [here](http://www.language-archives.org/language/rej).

Comment: Yes most Malayo-Polynesian languages can be trivially adapted to a subset of the Roman script. Google has a very nice Noto font for the abugida by the way. My practical reason for asking is to decide whether Wiktionary should support both scripts or just the abugida. But this stirs my general linguistic interest (-:

Comment: Russian Wiki says Rejang does use Latin script.

Comment: David Gil is the person I'd ask. He spends most of his time traveling among various SE Asian peoples and learning their languages well enough to do Max Plankinstitut language tests on them, and this includes lots of isolated Indonesian languages. I can get his email; he's on facebook too.